# A strange property of continuous deformations of balls

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $B$ be the closed unit ball in $\Bbb R^n$ and let
$$F:B\times[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R^n,\quad F(x,t)=F_t(x)$$
be a continuous map such that $F_0$ is the identity. In other words, $F$ defines a continuous deformation of $B$ in $\Bbb R^n$.

> **Question:** Show that for each time $t\in[0,\infty)$, there is a point $x\in B$ such that $F_t(x)$ lies in the line through $x$ and $0$. (Or $F_t(x)=0$ if $x=0$.)

[image]

**Attempt:** I am a bit clueless. In $\Bbb R^3$ the condition is that $x\times F_t(x)=0$, so we want to show that the map
$$H:B\to\Bbb R^3,\quad H_t(x)=x\times F_t(x)$$
has $H_t^{-1}(0)\neq\emptyset$. But that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy application of [Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).

Fix $t\in[0,\infty)$. Since $B$ is compact and $F_t$ is continuous, there exists $R>0$ such that $|F_t(x)|\le R$ for all $x\in B$. Then, we get a map
$$H_t:B\to B,\quad H_t(x)=\frac{F_t(x)}{R}.$$
By the aforementioned theorem, $H_t(x)=x$ for some $x\in B$, which is to say that
$$F_t(x)=Rx.$$